# pandas to_datetime formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to compare a pandas `to_datetime` object to another `to_datetime` object.  In both locations, I am entering the date as `date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-03')`, but when I run a print statement on each, in one case I get `2017-01-03`, but in another I get `2017-01-03 00:00:00`.  This causes a problem because if I use an if statement comparing them such as `if date1 == date2:` they will not compare as equal, when in reality they are.  Is there a format statement that I can use to force the `to_datetime()` command to yield the `2017-01-03` format?

Comment: I'm curious how you end up with two different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date()` method to just select date from pandas timestamp and also use `strftimeme(format)` method to convert it into string with different formats.

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-03').date()
print(date)
>datetime.date(2017, 1, 3)
```

or

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-03').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(date)
>'2017-01-03'
```

Answer (score 1):

try .date()

```
pd.to_datetime('2017-01-03').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pd.to_datetime().date()
```

For example:

```
a='2017-12-24 22:44:09' 
b='2017-12-24' 
if pd.to_datetime(a).date() == pd.to_datetime(b).date():
    print('perfect')
```